# Are there any methods toglobally login student in Flutter with Provider?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an application which connects with my API, whenever I log in token is stored to Shared Preferences and further auto login is possible. Whenever application reloads I log in with token stored in `SharedPrefs`, but when Main Screen loads I request get from my API `"api/me"` it sends stored token to server it returns me user with that token. But I also implemented dark theme switcher which value toggles between `true` and `false` in `SharedPref`s. And the data which I displaying in the app drawer (like user name and photo) suddenly disappears, BUT when I go to main screen again (app sends request to server) it occurs that it works again.

How to once get values from database and store it, keep access from every widget. I am using Provider.

Here is the code :

```
String token;

Future<Student> setStudent() async {
    
    try{
    
    final url = "https://myapi/me";
    Response res = await post(Uri.encodeFull(url), body:{'token': token});
    
    json.decode(res.body);
    
    } catch (e){
      print(e);
    }
    
    notifyListeners();

  }
}
```

And I use it in my Main Screen:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<StudentData>(context).setStudent().then((std) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          student = std;
        });
      });
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create ChangeNotifier that stores details regarding the app global state as stated : dark mode, api token, etc. You can inject this at the app level just above the app widget in the main method using ChaneNotifierProvider.

Now initially the you need to save the login status of the user in shared preferences as provider will exist in the app scope only while it's running.

So once the app loads just update the ChangeNotifier based on the shared preferences (needed only once) and the change will be reflected every and it will be available for use anywhere in the app